# Backbone.js router/views logic

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am writing my first Backbone.js application and I am having some trouble figuring out the best way to program it. I have 2 main views:

1. Shows an index of all my models.
2. Shows a specific model for editing.

But #2 has many different 'modules' like I can edit the 'news' section, or 'about' section etc...
All these modules are in a navigation bar.

That navigation bar is hidden when I am displaying view # 1 (index of all models). It is visible in view # 2(a specific model) in order to navigate between different modules.

I have routes setup like this:

```
routes: {
    '', 'index',
    'communities': 'index',
    'communities/:id': 'main',
    'communities/:id/news', 'news',
    'communities/:id/about', 'about'
},
```

So my question is, when 'news' or 'about' action is called, do I add a navigation bar in each method? Isn't that redundant? I am going to have like 8-10 different modules, add navigation bar each time seems very repetitive. Is there a better way?
The only time I want the navigation bar to be hidden is when showing index.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came across this same problem when I created my first *somewhat* complex Backbone app. Along with your concern of redundant code, I was concerned about events bound to my navbar that may not get unbound as the navigation bar changed.  To solve the problem, I wound up creating a view hierarchy, with one **manager** view managing the navigation bar a whole, and separate views for each type of navigation menu I wanted to display, which would be passed to the manager view to render to the page.

Here's an example of my implementation.

Before we start, here is a `close` function I added to Backbone's `View` prototype which unbinds events and removes the view

```
Backbone.View.prototype.close = function() {
    if(this.beforeClose) { this.beforeClose(); }
    this.remove();
    this.unbind();
}
```

First, here is my **Manager View**. Its `render` function closes whatever menu is currently displayed and replaces it with the one passed to it as `view`. While slightly redundant, I created an explicit `empty` function to make my router code easier to understand.

```
var App.Views.SubNavBar = Backbone.View.extend({

    currentView: null,

    el: '#subnav-wrap',

    render: function(view) {
        if(this.currentView) { this.currentView.close(); }
        this.currentView = view;
        this.$el.html(view.el);
    },

    empty: function() {
        if(this.currentView) { this.currentView.close(); }
        this.currentView = null;
    }

});
```

Second, here is a *base* view that all of my specific navigation menu views extend. Since they will all have the same `tagName`, `className`, `id`, and `initialize` and `render` functions, this keeps repetition to a minimum

```
var App.Views.SubNavBase = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'ul',

    className: 'nav nav-pills',

    id: 'subnav',

    template: _.template($('#tmpl-subnav').html(),

    initialize: function() {
        if(this.setLinks) { this.setLinks(); }
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template({links:this.links}));
        return this;
    }

});
```

Here is an example of a view for a specific navigation menu. You can see that all I need to do is define the links I want to appear in the menu. When I instantiate this view, the functions of `SubNavBase` will handle populating the view with the required HTML. Note that I also have some events attached to this view.

```
var App.Views.Projects.DisplayNav = App.Views.SubNavBase.extend({

    setLinks: function() {
        this.links = {
            'Edit Project': {
                icon: 'edit',
                class: 'menu-edit',
                href: '#projects/'+this.model.get('id')+'/edit'
            },
            'Add Group': {
                icon: 'plus',
                class: 'menu-add-group',
                href: '#projects/'+this.model.get('id')+'/groups/new'
            },
            'Delete Project': {
                icon: 'trash',
                class: 'menu-delete',
                href: '#'
            }
        }
    },

    events: {
        'click a.menu-delete' : 'delete'
    },

    delete: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // here goes my code to delete a project model
    }

});
```

Now, here is the underscore.js template I use to turn the links object above into a list of `<li>` elements. Note that I use `<@` instead of `<%` for my templates since this is a rails app and rails already uses `<%`

```
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-subnav">
    <@ _.each(links,function(link, title) { @>
    <li>
        <a href="<@= link.href @>" class="<@= link.class @>">
            <i class="icon-<@= link.icon @>"></i>
            <@= link.title @>
        </a>
    </li>
    <@ }); @>
</script>
```

Finally, to put it all together, here is an example `Router` function that creates and renders the nav menu. The steps that occur are as follows:

- `App.Views.Projects.DisplayNav` gets passed a model and populates its `this.el` with the corresponding HTML, as determined by the underscore.js template
- `App.SubNavBar` has its `render` function called with the new menu view
- `App.SubNavBar` checks to see if there is currently another menu in the navigation bar; if so, it calls its view's `close()` function
- `App.SubNavBar` finally appends the passed view's HTML to itself, maintaining a reference to the view for later use

I've included only the relevant parts of the router code

```
var App.Routers.Projects = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'projects/:id' : 'display'
    },

    display: function(id) {
        var p = projects.get(id);
        var subnav = new App.Views.Projects.DisplayNav({model:p})
        App.SubNavManager.render(subnav);  // App.SubNavManager is an instance of App.Views.SubNavBar
    }
});
```

The benefit to all of this is that I can now attach events to my menu-specific views, and the manager view will take care of unbinding them if the user navigates to different content and the menu changes.

Of course, there are many other patterns you can use to handle navigation menus, but hopefully this will help you on the path.

Comment: Dude, awesome answer. To be honest, later on thinking about it, I realized myself that having a view hierarchy is the best option. Then I saw this, and it's very detailed. Thanks again!!!!

Comment: @0xSina no problem. I went through a handful of attempts before settling on this approach, which I've come to like. I figure, might as well save someone else the time and hassle. I've also extended the 'manager' approach to other parts of my app that get reloaded with new content on a regular basis, e.g. the main content `div`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
routes: {
    '', 'index',
    'communities': 'index',
    'communities/:id': 'main',
    'communities/:id/:section': 'openSection'
},
openSection : function(id, section){
    if( section ){
        this.addNavigationBar();
    }
    switch( section ){
        case 'news' :
             this.news();
             break;
        case 'about' :
             this.about();
             break;
        default: 
             this.main();
    }
}
```

If your url contents a section you will add the navigation bar and then call you normal method as you have.